# why doesn't this shell work

Tags: shell, find, exec

Let's say there are directories and files like that:

- `./app/cores/a/conf/props.conf.indexer`
- `./app/cores/a/conf/props.conf.searcher`
- `./app/cores/b/conf/props.conf.indexer`
- `./app/cores/b/conf/props.conf.searcher`
- `./app/cores/c/conf/props.conf.indexer`
- `./app/cores/c/conf/props.conf.searcher`

After i deployed app directory to an indexer node, I want to change `app/cores/{core}/conf/props.conf.indexer` to `app/cores/{core}/conf/props.conf`.

Here is what I did:

```
find ./app/cores/*/conf -name "props.conf.indexer" -exec echo $( cd $(dirname {}) && mv props.conf.indexer props.conf && ls -d props.conf ) \;
```

but, it has returned (`props.conf.indexer` exists):

```
mv: rename props.conf.indexer to props.conf: No such file or directory
```

My question is whether it is impossible to use `{}` placeholder with `$()` expression or not.

Comment: The `$()` parts get executed by the shell *before* `find`.

Comment: thank you, that's what i wanted to know

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `echo` something that's already text, and everything inside `$()` is going to be evaluated *before* `find` (as @Biffen pointed out). And what's with the `ls -d`? Surely props.conf is not a directory?

This should do what you want:

```
for file in app/cores/*/conf/props.conf.indexer
do
    mv "$file" "${file%.indexer}"
done
```

Comment: they are not directory. and i wanted to deal with it with one line shell command.

Comment: @TaejunJang : one-liner shell commands are highly over-valued (IMHO), but you can convert this to one line : `for file in app/cores/*/conf/props.conf.indexer ; do mv "$file" "${file%.indexer}" ; done` (notice the `;` chars where I have joined the lines together. The cmd after `do` doesn't have to delimited with `;`). Good luck to all.